# keep rows corresponding to only some values in a column

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, reshape2

I have a data.table like following

```
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species pg rem_imp
 1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     qwe  1       3
 2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     qwe  1       3
 3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     qwe  5       3
 4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     qwe  2       3
 5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     qwe  2       3
 6:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     qwe  2       3
 7:          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     qwe  3       3
 8:          5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2     qwe  3       3
 9:          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     qwe  3       3
10:          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1     qwe  3       3
11:          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa 11       2
12:          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa 11       2
13:          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa 15       2
14:          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa 15       2
15:          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa 13       2

structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4, 4.6, 
5, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8, 4.8, 4.3, 5.8), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 
3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3, 3, 4), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 
1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.1, 
1.2), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2), Species = c("qwe", "qwe", 
"qwe", "qwe", "qwe", "qwe", "qwe", "qwe", "qwe", "qwe", "setosa", 
"setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa"), pg = c(1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 11, 11, 15, 15, 13), rem_imp = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), .Names = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", 
"Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species", "pg", "rem_imp"), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000011eb0788>)
```

I want to keep only those rows which correspond to first `rem_imp` values of column `pg` for each value of column `Species`. For example, For `qwe` I want to keep only first 3 (rem_imp column value) values of column `pg`. And for `setosa` I want to keep only first 2 values of column `pg`.

**EDIT: (Detailed explanation of what I want)**

What I want is to keep rows corresponding to first `rem_imp` unique values of `pg` for each `Species`. For example, for `qwe` I want to keep rows corresponding to first 3 unique values of `pg`. First 3 unique values of `pg` for `qwe` are 1,5 and 2, so we keep rows from 1 to 6. For `setosa` first 2 unique values of `pg` are 11 and 25, so we keep rows from 11 to 14 for `setosa`.

***The output will look like following***

```
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species pg rem_imp
 1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     qwe  1       3
 2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     qwe  1       3
 3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     qwe  5       3
 4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     qwe  2       3
 5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     qwe  2       3
 6:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     qwe  2       3
 7:          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa 11       2
 8:          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa 11       2
 9:          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa 15       2
10:          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa 15       2
```

I am sure this can be done in a single statement, but I am not able to do it successfully till now. **I am looking for a data.table syntax solution (basically a one line solution)**. I don't want to run a loop or something. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @docendodiscimus umm...so what you did was that you kept first `rem_imp` rows for each value of `Species`. What I want is to keep rows corresponding to first `rem_imp` unique values of `pg` for each `Species`. For example, for `qwe` I want to keep rows corresponding to first 3 unique values of `pg`. First 3 unique values of `pg` for `qwe` are 1,5 and 2, so we keep rows from 1 to 6. For `setosa` first 2 unique values of `pg` are 11 and 25, so we keep rows from 11 to 14 for `setosa`. You get it?

Comment: Yes, that make it clear.

Comment: @docendodiscimus the number of unique values of `pg` to keep gets decided by column `rem_imp`. For `qwe` it is 3 and for `setosa` it is 2.

Comment: got it. Already updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: Please update (edit) your question so that your intention is clear without reading comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option:

```
dt[dt[, cumsum(!duplicated(pg)) <= rem_imp[1L], by = Species]$V1]
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species pg rem_imp
# 1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     qwe  1       3
# 2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     qwe  1       3
# 3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     qwe  5       3
# 4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     qwe  2       3
# 5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     qwe  2       3
# 6:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     qwe  2       3
# 7:          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa 11       2
# 8:          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa 11       2
# 9:          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa 15       2
#10:          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa 15       2
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I don't want this. Please take a look at the desired output in my question. I don't want to keep x rows, but rows corresponding to first x unique values of column `pg`.